# Edit all multiple occurrences in Google Colab by selecting all and edit it as a single operation? Is there any shortcut?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, google-chrome, google-colaboratory

Edit all multiple occurrences in Google Colab with a single edit operation? Is there any shortcut to select all and edit all this at once?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a multiple line edit/ a mass edit shortcut.

You could use:

**1. Alt + Click for Windows**

**2. Option + Click for MacOS**

And to select all occurrences of the existing selection, use:

**1. Ctrl + Shift + L for Windows**

**2. Command + Shift + L for MacOS**

Comment: Now I can edit multiple occurrences in a single cell using: Ctrl + Shift + L for Windows. Then how can I edit multiple occurrences in multiple/ all cells?