# Google Colab select multiple variables shortcut?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am a Windows user and I want to know the shortcut key to automatically select multiple variables in Google Colab.

[image]

It used to be possible with **Ctrl+Shift+L**, but it's not working anymore.

I can manually select with **Alt+Click**, but I need an automatic shortcut key to select multiple variables.

[Edit all multiple occurrences in Google Colab by selecting all and edit it as a single operation? Is there any shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68938525/edit-all-multiple-occurrences-in-google-colab-by-selecting-all-and-edit-it-as-a)

I read above post, but Ctrl+Shift+L doesn't work.